# How do I connect my mysql database with node?

Tags: mysql, node.js, cmd, localhost, port

Through my git bash, I've run the command "npm install mysql" and then it downloads into my "C:\Users\Forrest\node_modules" directory. I've created an "insert.js" file in the same directory in hopes of creating a connection. When I try to actually connect, it gives me "throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event". I think this is because I actually haven't set up the database yet, so I try to run mysql with the command 'mysql -p' to create database articles. That works and it asks me to "Enter Password:" which I don't have so I just hit the enter key. This is where I get stuck. It says "ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)". For hours I have been trying to figure this out! Is there something wrong with the process I've gone through? Here is my insert.js code.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'articles'
});

connection.connect();

var article = {

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all install the SQL by command `npm install mysql`

Then you create a table with few tupples using `CREATE TABLE TABLENAME`

Then you need to connect to the SQL :-

```
var mysql = require("mysql");

// First you need to create a connection to the db
var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "username",
  password: "password"
});
```

Make sure you replace the user and password in the above syntax.

Define a body to make sure if any error occurs it throws the error back to you

THEN, You close the connection.

```
con.end(function(err)
```

Now open up a terminal and enter `node app.js`

if errors comes up please refer and fix them.

Comment: Without create database is it possible to create a table?

Answer (score 0):

Pardon me if this is a stupid question, but did you start up the mysql server first? I ask because the behavior you describe is exactly what you would expect to see if you did not. If you run mysql before starting the server, it will still ask you for a password, and then give you a 2003 error.

Before you can make a connection to a database, you must first start the mysql server by running the 'mysqld' program. If that does not work, you may also have issues with pathing: On my machine I had to tell mysql to look in the correct folder for the defaults file. It was looking in 'Program Files', when the /data folder and my.ini file were in 'ProgramData' instead.